Is there a way to display icons on Hard Links, similar to how there's a blue arrow for Junctions?
If you manually create a test directory. Then cd into it and type the following:
echo Test > test.txt
mkdir TempTesting
cd TempTesting
mklink /H linkTest.txt "../test.txt"

 
The Remaining Disk Space will not duplicate the value. But it's still a catastrophe when your view Properties of a Folder or a File on Windows Explorer.
An end-user does not have to use the Command Line just to figure out the ACTUAL correct file size.
This is present for Junctions as well. BUT ATLEAST there's a visual indication that it is a Junction. Does that exist for Hard Links as well?

There are multiple ways to check drive space, excluding hard links. This question is similar to: How can I check the actual size used in an NTFS directory with many hardlinks?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I edited it now. While still similar, this is about "ruining" the way on how to keep track what takes up space. Also with the point that there's no original way to tell which hard linked file is original. But if there would be, it could remove the file size of the file created after the hard link.
